# ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row while using select

Tags: sql, oracle

I guess the above question has been asked a couple of times... I am still not able to implement it in my query.. in the following query there is a service table of couple of employees whose employee id is present in temp table .... each employee might have worked in different places.. hence there may be more than one record for each employee.. i am trying to find out details of the last posting ... but at the third line i get the mentioned error.. in case I use "IN" instead of equal to ..  I get multiple records for each employee id

```
SELECT
    s.employee_id,
    s.from,
    s.to
FROM 
    service s, temp t
WHERE 
    t.employee_id = s.employee_id
    AND s.postnumber = (SELECT max(s1.postnumber)
                        FROM service s1, temp t1
                        WHERE t1.employee_id = s.employee_id)
ORDER BY 
    t.employee_id;
```

Comment: to properly understand what is happening this query the definition of temp and employee tables would be useful. In particular the primary key definition.

Comment: The subquery in the posted code returns exactly one row. The issue is happening elsewhere. Maybe it is this whole query that is used as a subquery (in the context of an expression)? Although that would already be wrong because of more than one column being returned.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a wrong where condition in your subquery: `t1.employee_id=s.employee_id`

and try `distinct` in subquery.

try this one:

```
select s.employee_id,s.from,s.to from service s,temp t
where t.employee_id=s.employee_id
and s.postnumber = (select distinct max(s1.postnumber) from service s1,temp t1 where     t1.employee_id=s1.employee_id)
order by t.employee_id;
```

Comment: i over looked that one... but even after replacing it with s1..it wont work.... but the distinct before max() has worked .. :) .. i shall have to c if i face any other problem ... thanks a lot

Comment: Why does it return multiple rows anyway? I always thought that using an aggregate function without `group by` resulted in zero or one records.

Comment: I agree with Caramiriel, the query has no way of going wrong. is this the exact query or is there any thing else...??

Comment: @Caramiriel: More exactly, that should always produce one row. That's why `distinct` here cannot possibly change anything.

Comment: @AndriyM: True. I noticed `null` will be selected when no elements are matched.

Comment: @Caramiriel : I was wondering may be u guys can shed some light over this..  the one thing i over looked (s1 in place of s) has given me the desired result...  as you said distinct didn't really make any difference .. now here is the query which gives zero or one record ..                                                 select s.employee_id,s.from,s.to from service s,temp t
where t.employee_id=s.employee_id
and s.postnumber = (select max(s1.postnumber) from service s1,temp t1 where t1.employee_id=s1.employee_id)
order by t.employee_id;

Comment: and  select s.employee_id,s.from,s.to from service s,temp t
where t.employee_id=s.employee_id
and s.postnumber = (select max(s1.postnumber) from service s1,temp t1 where t1.employee_id=s.employee_id)
order by t.employee_id;                                                gives me as data for as many records present in temp table

Comment: @gabbi: Can you provide us in the question a small `create table` statement with some minimal data? For some reason I don't think it has to do with this query. Are you using views of some sort?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please tell me that what is the point of joining table 'temp' when you are not using any of its columns in the SELECT clause.

Try putting that in an EXISTS clause.